# Are there any similar libjpeg API in Java?

Tags: jpeg, libjpeg, dct

I'm dealing with a project that requires me to read JPEG images and retrieve their DCT coefficients. I'll be doing it using Java.

Aware of the libjpeg API that is very useful and can be used to directly access the DCT of the images (used it with jpeg toolbox in MATLAB)

Are there any similar API to it in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [libjpeg-turbo](http://www.libjpeg-turbo.org). This library has support for Java.

From the website:

> libjpeg-turbo implements both the traditional libjpeg API as well as the less powerful but more straightforward TurboJPEG API. libjpeg-turbo also features colorspace extensions that allow it to compress from/decompress to 32-bit and big-endian pixel buffers (RGBX, XBGR, etc.), as well as a full-featured Java interface.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. I'll look it up and see whether it can implement the methods of libjpeg. I hope it can !