# Convert black and white Bitmap to Single-Channel JPEG in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, jpeg, android-bitmap

Is there any way to convert black and white bitmap to Single-Channel JPEG in Android?

I have a black and white bitmap that I create using `ARGB_8` config. I need to send to server a Base64 of **Single-Channel** JPEG. I tried compressing my bitmap using `Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, ...)` but I always get a 3-channel image. I tried using `ALPHA_8`, but because it uses a transparency layer when I compress it to JPEG it is simply ignored.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: no, you do NOT have to send base64. base64 is never the answer.

Comment: It is the answer for my usecase and I need to use it (send image and mask and generate new image with AI on server).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches.

(1) Use Libjpeg for Java. Its interface will probably allow you to do what you want.
[Are there any similar libjpeg API in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796267/are-there-any-similar-libjpeg-api-in-java#24813081)

(2) You could write a filter for your JPEG stream that strips out the all zero scans for the Cb and Cr components and edits the other markers for make it look like there is only one component.